# Use nested case, when and else condition in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I want to execute a stored procedure with 4 input parameters:

```
int A, B, C, D
```

and need to execute as

```
A/B - C/D
```

but I have to handle `Null` and `0` to avoid divide by zero exception.

I was trying this approach, but that didn't work out:

```
case when D is null or D = 0
       then case when B is null or B=0 then 0
                else cast(A/B) end
case when C is null or C=0
               case when B is null or B= 0, then 0
                else cast( A/B) end
case when A is null or A=0
               case when D is null or D= 0, then 0
                else cast(C/D) end
case when B is null or B=0
               case when D is null or D= 0, then 0
                else cast(C/D) end
else  cast (A/B - C/D) end as Result
```

Comment: Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61530470/edit) your question to add a sample data and the final results? eg: what's the values of `A, B, C, D` and what the SP should returns

Comment: I think the sign is wrong when "A/B" resolves to zero or NULL -- it should be `- C/D`.

Comment: yes minus sign to C/D is correct if A/B resolved to zero

Comment: thanks Sami, value would be any numeric like as integer or floating point number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here we can use ISNULL function also

CASE WHEN ISNULL(B,0) > 0 THEN  A/B ELSE 0 END) 
     - 
(CASE WHEN ISNULL(D,0) > 0 THEN  C/D ELSE 0 END)

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I am guessing you really want `- C/D` if `A/B` is not well-defined.

If so, you don't need a `case` expression at all:

```
(coalesce(A / nullif(B, 0), 0) -
 coalesce(C / nullif(D, 0), 0)
) as Result
```

Comment: thanks Gordon,
but there may be a chance that  A/B is well defined
inshort those 4 input value will be correct or might have 0 or null

Comment: @Anil . . . This takes that into account.

Comment: @Ross Bush thanks!
can you please re-post your answer

Comment: @Anil . . . This answer is logically equivalent, shorter, and appeared several minutes before the other answer.

Comment: @Anil . . . I'm surprised that you unaccepted this answer.  `ISNULL()` is a bespoke SQL Server function.  `COALESCE()` is standard SQL.

Comment: yes I have accepted this answer also, I forget to reply on your comments.Thank you so much !!! Really appreciated